# font-awesome in vue project is not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, font-awesome

I need to use font-awesome in my vue project to show some icon.
First, I installed font-awesome in my project.

```
npm install font-awesome --dev-save
```

After installed, it didn't work, just displayed as a square instead icon.
The error reason is the font file for font-awesome can't be loaded successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigation, I copied these font file to a new folder, and reset the variable $fa-font-path's value, like below:

```
// reset font-awesome variables
$fa-font-path:                    '/src/common/fonts'
```

And it works well. Hope could help.

Comment: In what file did you add the path.  Main.js, App.vue or some other file?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the fonts just by including

```js
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

in **main.js**.